# How to get this output using JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I am storing all student records who belongs to a particular class.

```
Class_ID|StudentID|Class_FEE
----------------------------
1001    |  0      |   100   
1001    |  101    |   50
```

Now another table stored student data while they registered on particular class

```
ClassID | StudentID
--------|-----------
1001    |   100
1001    |   101
```

Now on first table 0 indicates all students (here 100,101) . Now both have fees 100 but 101 got 50 for some purpose.

I need a o/p like

```
ClassID |  StudentID  | Amount
--------|-------------|--------
1001    |   100       |100
1001    |   101       |  50 (here 50 <100 so taking 50)
```

Comment: I am saying 0 means all students who registered with classid 1001. On second table I mentioned that too sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested about the minimum fee belonging to each student you can use this

```
select r.classid , r.studentid, min(b.Class_FEE)
from registered r
join belongs b on b.classid = r.classid and 
                 (b.studentid = r.studentid or 0 = b.studentid)
group by r.classid , r.studentid
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=19859e4fbc534d352913321688394140)

**Result**

```
ClassID StudentID   Amount
-------------------------------------
1001    100         100
1001    101         50
```

Comment: @Babai you are wellcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select sc.studentid,
       (case when f.fee < f0.fee then f.fee else f0.fee end) as fee
from studentclass sc left join
     fees f
     on sc.studentid = f.studentid and sc.classid = f.classid left join
     fees f0
     on sc.classid = f0.classid and f0.studentid = 0;
```

This version assumes (as in your sample data) that the a student/class combination only appears once in the fee table.

Comment: I believe it is not correct: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ef1e120cec9c8df549e9ae46b59b42f7

Comment: @RadimBača . . . Good catch.  Adding the fees makes more sense to me than taking the minimum, but the latter is what the op is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
DECLARE @particularclass TABLE (Class_ID int, StudentID int, Class_FEE int)
DECLARE @regclass TABLE (ClassID int, StudentID int)
INSERT INTO @particularclass VALUES (1001,0,100), (1001,101,50)
INSERT INTO @regclass VALUES (1001,100), (1001,101)

SELECT R.*
      ,COALESCE((SELECT MIN(Class_FEE) FROM @particularclass P WHERE P.StudentID = R.StudentID)
               ,(SELECT CLass_FEE FROM @particularclass P WHERE P.StudentID = 0)) AS [Amount]
  FROM @regclass R
```